# NextJs Page first page dynamic second not

Tags: next.js, dynamic, static, server-side-rendering

### [See Build output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa1dm.jpg)

├ ○ /models                              1.07 kB         128 kB <-- [Static] Why?
├ λ /models/page/[page]                  1.07 kB         128 kB <-- [Dynamic]
other pages with pagination are [Dynamic]

### [See Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3okM.jpg)

### /models

```
import Wrapper from '@/components/layout/Wrapper'
import Header from '@/components/layout/Header'
import Navigation from '@/components/layout/Navigation'
import Content from '@/components/layout/Content'
import ModelsPageComponent from '@/components/ModelsPageComponent'

import {
    MODELS_PAGE_MODELS_FETCH,
} from '@/API/endpoint'

async function getData() {
    const data = await MODELS_PAGE_MODELS_FETCH(1, 22)
    return data
}

export default async function ModelsPage() {
    const data = await getData()

    async function fetchData(page: number) {
        'use server'
        const data = await MODELS_PAGE_MODELS_FETCH(page, 22)
        return data
    }
    
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <Header />
            <Navigation />
            <Content>
                <ModelsPageComponent data={data} fetchData={fetchData} />
            </Content>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}
```

### /models/page/[page]

```
import Wrapper from '@/components/layout/Wrapper'
import Header from '@/components/layout/Header'
import Navigation from '@/components/layout/Navigation'
import Content from '@/components/layout/Content'
import ModelsPageComponent from '@/components/ModelsPageComponent'

import {
    MODELS_PAGE_MODELS_FETCH,
} from '@/API/endpoint'

async function getData(page: number) {
    const data = await MODELS_PAGE_MODELS_FETCH(page, 22)
    return data
}

export default async function ModelsPaginationPage({ params } : any) {
    const page = params.page;
    const data = await getData(page)
    
    async function fetchData(page: number) {
        'use server'
        const data = await MODELS_PAGE_MODELS_FETCH(page, 22)
        return data
    }

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <Header />
            <Navigation />
            <Content>
                <ModelsPageComponent data={data} fetchData={fetchData} />
            </Content>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}
```

can someone tell me why?